# Selecting R and C values for a second-order active bandpass filter

Tags: circuit-design, filter, band-pass

I am using the below second-order active bandpass filter in my breathing rate sensor. I need to have a passband of 0.1 to 10 Hz with -6dB attenuation at these frequencies.

I am not sure what I need to do to the critical frequency formulas below in order to get -6dB attenuation instead of -3dB.

I have read some stuff about the Q factor but I am not sure how to proceed from here.

[image]

Comment: Simulation would seem a useful (and accurate) way to solve this.

Comment: Do you know differential equations or Laplace Transforms?

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd order bandpass filter always has the transfer form of the following expression:

$$K\frac{\frac1{Q}\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}}{\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}^2+\frac1{Q}\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}+1}$$

where \$K\$ (which may be sometimes given as \$A\$ or \$h\$ or who knows what else) is the gain factor, \$\omega_{_0}\$ is the geometric center angular frequency, and \$Q\$ is the filter shape.

In your case, we can solve (and then set aside) \$\omega_{_0}=2\pi\sqrt{100\:\text{mHz}\,\cdot\,10\:\text{Hz}}=2\pi\cdot 1\:\text{Hz}\$, because it has nothing to do with your goal of \$-6\:\text{dB}\$ at the given skirts except positioning along the (angular) frequency axis.

What's left is \$K\$ and \$Q\$.

Regarding the use of \$K\$, I'm going to paraphrase an old quote from somewhere: *"The only guaranteed way to become a millionaire is to start off a billionaire and then lose some it."* So, you could start out with a bandpass filter of some shape and skirts at \$-3\:\text{dB}\$, for example, and then just intentionally (passively with a resistor divider) "lose some." That could get you there. So if you knew a specific shape you really needed but it provided too much gain for you, then you could just lose some.

But if you are looking to find a filter shape that gives you the \$-6\:\text{dB}\$ skirts at the points indicated and are willing to accept the \$K\$ you get, then that's a different question.

Let's just set \$\omega_{_0}=1\$, as at first we don't need to worry about it when considering your question. Also, there's really no need to complicate things with \$K\$ just yet, either. So \$K=1\$ for now.

$$\frac{\frac1{Q}s}{s^2+\frac1{Q}s+1}$$

Nice and simple. There's only one independent parameter to play with now.

By replacing \$s=j\omega\$ and using \$\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\$ equal either 0.1 or 10 (doesn't matter) we can just solve for \$Q\$:

$$10^{^\frac{-6}{20}}=\left.\middle|\frac{j\frac{0.1}{Q}}{1-0.1^2+j\frac{0.1}{Q}}\middle|\right.$$

That solves out to \$Q=0.1744\$ when \$K=1\$. Here's the plot when \$f_{_0}=1\:\text{Hz}\$.

[image]

You can see this is exactly as expected.

Now, if this is ***not*** the shape you wanted then you will need to specify the shape and then solve for \$K\$.

Suppose you wanted \$Q=4\$? Then the solution gives \$K\approx 19.85\$. Here's a plot of that one:

[image]

And here are both superimposed on each other:

[image]

This should help you understand better that you either need to know the shape (\$Q\$) or the gain (\$K\$) to solve for the other one.

Once those are resolved, then you can plug back in \$\omega_{_0}\$ to get the final transfer function and work out the resistor and capacitor values.

---

Finally, note that simulation is there to confirm theory. Not to hunt and peck for values. It's a lot better to know why and be able to judge what you get from simulation, than to have no ability to discern on your own and therefore to be forced to accept what simulation seems to be saying.

If you want to read a fun and educational story about why theory is prior, then please enjoy [*Derivation of Theory by Means of Factor Analysis or Tom Swift and His Electric Factor Analysis Machine*](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/47256/derivationoftheo00arms.pdf?sequence=1) by J. Scott Armstrong (then at MIT), circa 1967 (I think.) If that doesn't hammer home why simulation doesn't teach knowledge, nothing ever will.

Comment: This was great. Thank you @periblepsis. What would the formula be for calculating Q? I need to select R and C values.

Comment: Also I am plugging that formula into wolfram alpha and I am getting values with j in them, not equal to 0.1744. How did you calculate this?

Comment: @palacetrading I just used Python:  `solve(Eq(abs((0.1*I/Q)/(1-.1**2+0.1*I/Q)),10**(-6/20)),Q)` and got `[-0.174401821558936, 0.174401821558936]`. The abs() function works with complex numbers and produces a magnitude from the sqrt() of the real part squared plus the imaginary part squared.